# Exception thrown when verifying fingerprint from mysql database

Tags: mysql, vb.net, fingerprint, biometrics

Can someone help me how to solve my problem? I am using visual studio 2013 vb.net and my database is mysql. I have a table on my database `user` and has the field `id` which is auto increment int and `print` data type is blob. When saving finger print the blob gets value which is 65kb in size, so I assume that's already the fingerprint. But when I try to verify it, may application stops working and show me this error message:

`An exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in DPFPVerNET.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: Exception from HRESULT: 0xFFFFFFF8`

Is there a problem on the `DPFPVerNET.dll` or it is just my code?

Here is my code anyway.

```
connectDB()

    Dim printFDB As DPFP.Template = New DPFP.Template
    Dim virifyFDB As New DPFP.Verification.Verification
    Dim memStream As MemoryStream

    Dim da As New MySqlDataAdapter
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim data As Byte()

    Dim selectCom As New MySqlCommand("select * from user", con)

    With da
        .SelectCommand = selectCom
        .Fill(dt)
    End With

    For i = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
        data = dt.Rows(i)("print")



        memStream = New MemoryStream(data)

        printFDB.DeSerialize(memStream)

        MyBase.Process(Sample)


        Dim features As DPFP.FeatureSet = ExtractFeatures(Sample, DPFP.Processing.DataPurpose.Verification)


        If Not features Is Nothing Then

            Dim result As DPFP.Verification.Verification.Result = New DPFP.Verification.Verification.Result()
            Verificator.Verify(features, printFDB, result)
            UpdateStatus(result.FARAchieved)
            If result.Verified Then
                MakeReport("The fingerprint was VERIFIED.")
            Else
                MakeReport("The fingerprint was NOT VERIFIED.")
            End If
        End If


    Next
disconnectDB()
```

I need some guidance. Thank you.

---

This is the error:

`DPFP.Error.SDKException: Event Handler has generated an Exception ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Exception from HRESULT: 0xFFFFFFF8
   at DPFP.Verification.Verification.MC_verifyFeaturesEx(SafeHandle mcContext, Int32 templateSize, Byte[] templatePt, Int32 featureSetSize, Byte[] featureSet, Int32 reserved0, IntPtr reserved1, IntPtr reserved2, IntPtr reserved3, Double& achievedFar)
   at DPFP.Verification.Verification.Verify(FeatureSet FeatureSet, Template Template, Int32 FARRequested)
   at DPFP.Verification.Verification.Verify(FeatureSet FeatureSet, Template Template, Result& Result)
   at Enrollment.VerificationForm.Process(Sample Sample) in C:\Program Files\DigitalPersona\One Touch SDK\.NET\Samples\Visual Studio 2005\VBNET\Enrollment\VerificationForm.vb:line 65
   at Enrollment.CaptureForm.OnComplete(Object Capture, String ReaderSerialNumber, Sample Sample) in C:\Program Files\DigitalPersona\One Touch SDK\.NET\Samples\Visual Studio 2005\VBNET\Enrollment\CaptureForm.vb:line 79
   at DPFP.Capture.Capture.MessageReceived(Message& m)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at DPFP.Error.ExceptionFactory.Throw(Exception Exception, ErrorCodes ErrorCode, String ErrorMessage)
   at DPFP.Capture.Capture.MessageReceived(Message& m)
   at DPFP.Capture.Capture.MessageEvents.MessageWindow.WndProc(Message& m)`

Comment: Set a breakpoint then come back and let us know where the issue is.

Comment: Edited my post and added the error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hai, You got any solution for this? I am facing the same problem. Please reply me ASAP.